# How to find and replace string in MYSQL that have <> " ' in database?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

i'm not an expert in mysql but i need to find and replace the data

```
<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>
   <div class="ui-box-body">
     <p> &nbsp; </p> <h2 style="padding: 5.0px;">


  <div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;"><div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
```

i try to use this command

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_description` 
WHERE  `description` LIKE '%<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>    <div class="ui-box-body">      <p> &nbsp; </p> <h2 style="padding: 5.0px;">     <div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;"><div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;"> %'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but it return 0 results

i need to find and replace the value with ""  in my table description how to do that?
and if i search using this command

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_description` 
WHERE  `description` LIKE  '% <h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

it will return the results Showing rows 0 - 29

please advise need help from expert. appreciated. thanks

Comment: Are the numbers of spaces in the data exactly as you've shown in your LIKE?

Comment: The line returns are probably missing from your SQL, but present in the database.

Comment: Why are html-tags saved in db?

Comment: You are asking for trouble doing that. Any string replacement in markup is fraught with the potential for error. Is this a one off task?

Answer (score 0):

### Why your code is not working

Spacing of the code in database may be different from the given one.

### Solution

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$1 = '<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>';
$2 = '<div class="ui-box-body">';
$3 = '<p> &nbsp; </p> <h2 style="padding: 5.0px;">';
$4 = '<div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;"><div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">';
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db"); //edit parameters
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_description` 
WHERE  `description` LIKE '%".$1."%' AND `description` LIKE '%".$2%."'`description` LIKE '".%$3%."' AND `description` LIKE '%".$4%."'
LIMIT 0 , 30";
$query = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==1){echo 'Found the correct string!<br>';
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $assoc['description'];
}
else if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>1){echo 'Found too much results!';}
else{echo 'Found nothing!';}
?>
```

### If this doesn't work anyway

You could have escaped html strings before the insertion in the database.
Replace

```
$1 = '<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>';
$2 = '<div class="ui-box-body">';
$3 = '<p> &nbsp; </p> <h2 style="padding: 5.0px;">';
$4 = '<div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;"><div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">';
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db"); //edit parameters
```

With

```
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db"); //edit parameters
$1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,'<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>');
$2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,'<div class="ui-box-body">');
$3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,'<p> &nbsp; </p> <h2 style="padding: 5.0px;">');
$4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,'<div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;"><div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">');
```

If you still don't get the expected result, it is possible that you had used `htmlspecialchars()`, maybe in addition to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.
Edit variables $1,$2,$3 and $4 adding `htmlspecialchars`, if it doesn't work try to remove `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Hi thanks for fast response. i have try the both code but it didn't work the page is still blank page. i do test only 1 line but also same. thanks and appreciated

Comment: It's blank because the code I posted doesn't print nothing, because I din't know what you needed to do with the selected field. Check my updated answer. Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE oc_product_description SET description = REPLACE(description, '<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2><div class="ui-box-body"><p> &nbsp; </p> <h2 style="padding: 5.0px;"><div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;"><div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">', '')
WHERE description LIKE ('%<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2><div class="ui-box-body">      <p> &nbsp; </p><h2 style="padding: 5.0px;"><div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;"><div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;"> %');
```

but before trying that just keep a backup of the table.